# Testing Spring Boot Rest Api with hasSize() with hamcrest throws errors

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test a REST API. For this I use the following code.
However, Intellij gives me the error in the last line:

> Not enough information to infer type variable T.

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize


mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users"))
.andDo(print())
.andExpect(status().isOk)
.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$").isNotEmpty)
.andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray)
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(2)));
```

Comment: Which line is IntelliJ complaining about? Can you please highlight it?